# Replacement in visual mode

Tags: visual-mode, replace

I wrote a function for selecting a text region and replacing in it certain predefined characters:

```
fun! Tstrepl() range
    s/\%Va/\="\u2227"/ge  " 'a' to '∧'
    s/\%Vb/\="\u2228"/ge  " 'b' to '∨'
endfun

vnoremap QQ :call Tstrepl()<CR>
```

The problem is that the function doesn't behave as expected and I cannot figure out why.

The following text is handled OK:

```
BEFORE: bbbaaa
AFTER: ∨∨∨∧∧∧
```

But another text isn't handled OK:

```
BEFORE: aaabbb
AFTER: ∧∧∧bbb
```

What's wrong with the function?

Comment: I think this is because you use multi-byte characters in the replacement field of the substitution commands. And because Vim – probably – keeps track of the start/end of the visual selection via *byte* indexes (not character indexes). When you replace a character whose weight is 1 byte, with a character whose weight is 2 bytes, Vim should update the end of the visual selection it had saved originally; it probably doesn't.
Does [this code](https://0x0.st/zTH7.txt) help? (make sure `*` is not in the value of `'cpoptions'`)

Comment: @user938271 Thanks for the solution! It works.

Comment: @user938271 this should be a full answer, not a comment and paste-binned code. Please move your comment into an answer (and code with it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is because you use multi-byte characters in the replacement field of the substitution commands. And because Vim – probably – keeps track of the start/end of the visual selection via *byte* indexes (not character indexes). When you replace a character whose weight is 1 byte, with a character whose weight is 2 bytes, Vim should update the end of the visual selection it had saved originally; it probably doesn't.

Try this code:

```
fu! s:Tstrepl() abort
    let vcol = [virtcol("'<"), virtcol("'>")]
    let pat = '\%>' . (vcol[0]-1) . 'v\%<' . (vcol[1]+1) . 'v'
    exe '*s/' . pat . 'a/\="\u2227"/ge'
    exe '*s/' . pat . 'b/\="\u2228"/ge'
endfu
xno <silent> QQ :<c-u>call <sid>Tstrepl()<cr>
```

Make sure `*` is not in the value of `'cpoptions'`.

For more information, see:

```
:h /\%v
:h virtcol()
```

Comment: What is the range `*` in `*s/` ?

Comment: It's an alias for `'<,'>`. See `:h cpo-star`.

Answer (score 1):

user938271 already gave an explanation why OP had this problem.
Here is another solution:

```
vnoremap QQ :s/\v%V[ab]/\=submatch(0)=='a'?"\u2227":"\u2228"/g<cr>
```

- `\v%V[ab]` search `a` or `b` in visual area.
- `\=submatch(0)=='a'?"\u2227":"\u2228"` replace `a` with `"\u2227"`, `b` with `"\u2228"`. `submatch(0)` is the whole matched text.